# Serial communication between Raspberry pi and Arduino unsuccessful

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I am making a project in which I have connected both Arduino Uno and Rasberry pi with the simple usb used to connect Arduino and pc. I am trying to get the sensor reading only when I need for which i am using this code:-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/project $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
>>> ser.write(b'sensors')
7
>>> input = ser.readline()
>>> print(input)
b'37.20 32.50 0 995\r\n'
>>>
```

But when I put the same code in a python file and try to run it, it just gets stuck at ser.readline(). On adding timeout, it just returns an empty string.
the python file code is :-

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)

ser.write(b'sensors')
input = ser.readline()
print(input)
```

Can anyone help me out?
I know that the write message is reaching Arduino because I was able to start led and other components easily. Raspberry pi is just not reading the message from Arduino.

My Arduino code is:-

```
#include <DHT.h>;
#define DHTPIN 2     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

int rain_sensor_pin = 4;
int led_pin = 13;
int ldr_pin = A0;
float hum, temp;
int rain, ldr;
String message;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(rain_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  dht.begin(); 
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
    message = Serial.readString();
    message_action();
  }
}

void message_action(){
  if(message == "sensors"){
    sensors();
  }else {
    action();
  }
}

void sensors(){
  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  temp= dht.readTemperature();
  rain = digitalRead(rain_sensor_pin);
  ldr = analogRead(ldr_pin);
  Serial.println(String(hum) + " " + String(temp) + " " + String(rain) + " " + String(ldr));
}

void action(){
  if (message == "light_on"){
    digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
  }else if (message == "light_off"){
    digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `time.sleep(...)` after write and read

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: I am able to make the code working by continuously printing the values to serial by arduino though